# How can I save an async return value in a variable?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var password = "Bacon";
var securePassword;
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(bacon, salt, function(err, hash) {
        securePassword = hash
    });
});
console.log(securePassword)
```

This returns *undefined* probably due to Async. How can I store the hash value, in the variable securePassword?

Comment: it is storing it, you're just trying to access it before it has a value

Comment: So in other words, you're saying that I can't accomplish that in async?

Comment: you probably need a callback or at least to wait for the call to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the value of hash to `securePassword` in the  `bcrypt.hash` callback function which is correct.. but as that is a callback function your console.log will execute before `securePassword` is assigned..

solution to this is to do your logic in that callback handle.

You can also use different methods like promise to resolve it you can read more from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```js
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var password = "Bacon";
var securePassword;
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(bacon, salt, function(err, hash) {
        securePassword = hash
        dologic()
        //console.log(securePassword)
        //or have a function with this statement
    });
});
function dologic(){
console.log(securePassword)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with `asynchronous` function.

---

**GOOD**

```
var securePassword;

bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    bcrypt.hash(bacon, salt, function(err, hash) {
        securePassword = hash;

        console.log(securePassword);
    });
});
```

---

**GOOD**

```
function generateSalt(callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(bacon, salt, callback);
    });
}

generateSalt((err, hash) => {
  if (err) // Handle error

  console.log(hash);
});
```